# Multiple like conditions for same column?

Tags: oracle

How do I write a query for a Oracle database when I have several "like" values for the same column (in my example data "name")?

My example data for table "address":

```
name like "John"
name like "Jon%"
name like "Jonathan"
name like "Frank"
```

Is there something like `IN()` with `LIKE` in Oracle or do I have to write it for each value `OR` separated?

Comment: Oracle has REGEXP_LIKE (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) .

Comment: @a1ex07 thank you for the notice, I will keep it in my mind. But I'm looking for a more common solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `OR` would be the way to go, yes.

Comment: Possibly the shortest valid answer the site will ever see.